# SFTP server to respond with HTTPS file

Tags: server, ssh, proxy, sftp, https

I have a REST-API server by HTTPS. I need a way to call the API when a file is retrieved using SFTP. The content is dynamically generated per request. Is there a simple way to do that without having to add user accounts and introduce security holes on the server? Having the key will allow anyone to get the content of the file, but nothing else.

This is what I have:

```
GET https://myservice/api/items/get?key=XXXX
```

and doing this shall return the same:

```
sftp XXXX@myservice:/items (or sftp myservice:/items/XXXX)
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you mean. You want to generate a file based on the current user (or requested file). You currently do that over HTTPS but you want to also make it available over SFTP... Right? Interesting problem.

You might be shocked to hear that I don't think there's anything that can do what you're asking out of the box.... Anything's possible though.

---

My first approach involves writing your own filesystem!

I'd start with FUSE. Moreover, python-fuse. Here's [the only tutorial I've ever used](http://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/) for FUSE. It'll get you to the point where you can start to edit things. I would:

- Have it list just one [fake] file in `readdir()`
- Work out how to find the username from the filesystem
- Hotwire `open()` and `read()` to pull from a `requests.get('your URL')` using the username. `open()` might just need to be faked and `read()` be a handle on the `requests` request.
- You'll probably need to patch up and dummy many of the other methods so they return data but it'll obviously be faked most of the time
- Mount this FUSE filesystem somewhere in your SFTP that everybody can see as readonly

This would work for either sftp approach (you could look at the full path instead of the user, for example) but you'll need a single sftp account that people can log in with.

---

Alternatively, if every user has an account, you could try to monitor access to a directory owned by each user. `inotifywatch` and `inotifywait` can let you watch for access to a directory.

```
inotifywait -mrq --format '%w' /home/*/magicdir/ | while read DIR; do
    user=${DIR:6:-10}  # that is based on the length of /home/ and /magicdir/
    wget -qO $DIR https://path/to/items/${user}
done
```

And leave that running somewhere in the background. It'll update the file from the website everytime they access the directory. You might want to check it (with an `echo blaaa $DIR`) to make sure it's not hammering the server. It may not display a file the first time they load the directory.

Comment: That is what I wanted yes. But I had hoped to avoid writing this tool myself. I found httpfs2 but it doesn't seem to be able to cope with https.

Comment: Hmm, overlooked that. Kept finding the Hadoop httpfs when I was searching for things like that. Later versions of httpfs2 support SSL/TLS: "As of 0.1.5 SSL is enabled when GNUTLS 2.10 or higher is present." So if you downloaded the source and compiled it yourself, that might work. But writing your own isn't as awful as it sounds if you have any programming experience. FUSE handles most of the heavy lifting.